# How do I declare a field in my .net class object as an xml child node for serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

Using Visual Studio 2010, C# .Net4, I am building a website that I want to send data from the hosting server to the client browser via XML.

My data is in a object (class) e.g.:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class InitialDataForBrowser
{
    public string myParentNode;
    public string myChildNode;


    public InitialDataForBrowser()
    {

    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string _myChildNode
    {
        set
        {
            myChildNode = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce the results:

```
<myParentNode></myParentNode>
<myChildNode ></myChildNode >
```

How can I declare child node elements within the object so produces:

```
<myParentNode>
    <myChildNode ></myChildNode >
</myParentNode>
```

I am writing this above object to the XML file by using:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("XMLFile.xml", FileMode.Create);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InitialDataForBrowser));
xs.Serialize(fs, data);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Can you clarify something: there is no actual difference between the two xml blocks shown... what is it you want to achieve differently? Also: wouldn't json be a better choice for a client browser?

Comment: do you mean  <myParentNode>
    <myChildNode ></myChildNode ></myParentNode>?

Comment: @Ivan I modified your question so that it reflects what you asked, if this is incorrect let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you meant what dumdum said you can achieve what your looking for my using "Has A" relationships:

```
public class InitialDataForBrowser
{
    public ParentNode Parent { get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }

    public InitialDataForBrowser()
    {
        Parent = new ParentNode();
        MyName = "InitialDataForBrowser";
    }
}

public class ParentNode
{
    public ChildNode Child { get; set; }

    public string MyName { get; set; }

    public ParentNode()
    {
        Child = new ChildNode();
        MyName = "Parent";
    }
}

public class ChildNode
{
    public string MyName { get; set; }

    public ChildNode()
    {
        MyName = "Child";
    }
}
```

If you serialise `InitialDataForBrowser` you will get the xml you want. Remember you need to actually instantiate the values. You can't serialise what you don't have. (There are options for Null serialisation but I don't think that's what you want).

Comment: Sorry, yes - I do mean <myParentNode> <myChildNode ></myChildNode ></myParentNode>

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class InitialDataForBrowser
{
    public string myField = "myValue";
    public ParentNode Parent { get; set; }
}
public class ParentNode
{
    public string parentNodeField = "ParentValue";
    public ChildNode Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildNode
{
    public string childNodeField = "ChildValue";
}

Comment: <InitialDataFromServer>
  <myField>myValue</myField>
</InitialDataFromServer>

Comment: Have you marked Child as [XMLIgnore] This will ignore it. It is only seeing your myField property not the Parent.

Comment: Hang on, I'm assuming you set up the properties.. one sec Ill edit.